# p:autoComplete query based on p:selectOneMenu value returns null with AJAX

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete, selectonemenu

I am new to JSF2. I am using a Selectonemenu component to get list of countries in the table, and based on what user choose in the dropdown list, the autocomplete component will perform a complete method querying another database table, the ajax method when I change values on Selectonemenu it is printing right the chosen value but when i try to get it in my autocomplete function it's returning null. 
Here's my code:

```
String country;
// Getter and setter

public String set_country_name(){   
    System.out.println(country);  ==>this is working
    return country;
}

public List<Place> completePlace(String query) {

    List<Place> filteredPlaceNames = new ArrayList<Place>();
    System.out.println(set_country_name()); // this is returning null
    ResultSet result;

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mytable where country_name = ? AND place_name = ? ");
        ps.setString(1, country);
        ps.setString(2, query);
        result = ps.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {
            Place p = new Place();
            //s.setId(result.getInt("id"));
            p.setPlace_id(result.getInt("place_id"));
            //s.setActive(result.getInt("active"));
            p.setPlace_name(result.getString("place_name"));
            filteredPlaceNames.add(p);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filteredPlaceNames;
}
```

my XHTML: (I already tried execute and event tags I've got same result)

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="Country :" />
    <p:spacer width="100" height="10" />

    <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{autoCompletePlace.country}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.placesName}" />
        <p:ajax process="@this" listener="#{autoCompletePlace.set_country_name}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:autoComplete id="place_name"
                    value="#{autoCompletePlace.place}"
                    completeMethod="#{autoCompletePlace.completePlace}"
                    size="40" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Yes sorry I updated that on my code and same problem, it's starting null when I start typing in the autocomplete but it returns the correct value when I change selectonemenu items

Comment: Ok I'm updating my xhtml code I think I put the non modified one.

Comment: When I am changing selectonemenu options, the `System.out.println(country);` inside `public String set_country_name()` is printing correctly but when I start typing in the autocomplete the `System.out.println(set_country_name());` inside the `public List<Place> completePlace(String query)` is printing 2 `null` it means that it's not updated or what?

Comment: What is the scope of the bean? If it is the request scoped, the value of the country you select will not be preserved on subsequent post requests (post-backs). It should at lest be a view scoped bean (and business logic should be placed in its own place precisely the service layer but in this case, it should be a method decorated with `@PostConstruct` at least).

Comment: @Tiny Yes I was ursing a request scoped bean, I changed it to a view Scoped bean now and it's working fine, but it's throwing in the console this `INFO: CDI @ViewScoped manager unavailable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual` and `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual`

Comment: Do you use CDI from Java EE (or Spring)? In that case (if you use CDI. Hence, beans are managed by the container itself),  you should be using the view scope annotation from `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` or if you want to stick at JSF managed beans and unwilling to use CDI, use a view scope from JSF itself `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`. The message symptom appears to indicate that you are using Spring on a bare-bone Servlet container like Tomcat  in which I am not sure about how to enable the CDI context.

Comment: Yes I am using Spring Security, I fixed it by adding the CDI api jar file to my lib. It's working fine now, thanks dude :)